# SQLite Android method update

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I would like to my query to the database look like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET salary = salary + cash WHERE id_wallet = id_wallet2
```

cash and id_wallet2- transmitted by method

I wrote this method. But the method changes the salary, do not bear the extra money. Do you have any ideas how to do it?

```
  public void AddCashWallet(int id_wallet, double cash){
    ContentValues contentValues1 = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
    contentValues2.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.id_walllet, id_wallet);
    contentValues1.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.currency_cash,cash);
    DbHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(Wallets.TABLE_NAME,contentValues1,""+contentValues2,null);
}
```

But I want my query look like this: `UPDATE table_name SET salary = salary + cash WHERE id_wallet = id_wallet2` In this moment look like: `UPDATE table_name SET salary = cash WHERE id_wallet = id_wallet2`

Comment: It's `INSERT` so its `add`, not `update`. You may want to correct your title

Answer (score -1):

That's not how to update.

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.currency_cash,cash);

String selection = Wallets.COLUMNS.id_walllet + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(id_wallet) };

DbHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(
    Wallets.TABLE_NAME,contentValues,selection,selectionArgs);

}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Ok. But I want my query look like this:                                                UPDATE table_name SET salary = salary + cash WHERE id_wallet = id_wallet2                                                                                                    In this moment look like:                                                               UPDATE table_name SET salary = cash WHERE id_wallet = id_wallet2

Comment: You may be better off doing that with raw SQL.